# Is there a culture where traditionally women fish?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, gender, fishing

I guess as far as the social aspects of worldbuilding are concerned, pretty much anything goes but I'd still like to incorporate elements that aren't far-fetched in terms of real-world applicability.

So the society I'm working with is matrilineal but NOT matriarchal. Property is passed down on the female line and women dominate in their families and many crafts, therefore they hold a very prestigious status in society. In addition, their religion is centered around a sun goddess whose worship is so predominant that this belief system is basically semi-monotheistic (spirits, demigods and other divine beings are also worshipped but to a much smaller degree). In day to day life, men and women are seen as equal intellectually.

That being said, political power is concentrated in the hands of men: most government officials are male, the monarch himself is always a man and men are promoted faster. Furthermore, gender roles, albeit not too strict or rigid, do exist. However, that doesn't automatically dictate what professions women might dominate in, as gender roles are quite versatile across cultures, yet fishing is almost universally seen as a men's thing. So would it make sense for fishing to be a female-dominated occupation where women are not just fishwives but actually the ones partaking in the entire activity? Is there a real-world example of this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure so can only post it as a comment, but there are japanese women who are specialized in fishing. You can also think of the women fishing for crabs and shells in the tropical archipelagos, I guess

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the real world not about building a fictional world. Do you have a specific question about the world you're building, instead of a request for examples of something in the real world?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "fishing". Traditional [Japanese female pearl divers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ama_(diving)) are well known, as, for example, Ian Fleming's [Kissy Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissy_Suzuki). If you mean fishing as going to sea in small boats and hauling big heavy nets full of fish, that's men's job as men are both stronger and expendable. In a premodern world women are *precious;* no sane society will assign them to very dangerous jobs, because that would risk its own future.

Comment: @sphennings According to the [help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), asking for real-world examples to help with a particular history for a world is on topic. [This meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate) linked in the help centre also specifically states that real-world questions are on-topic as long as they help to build one's world.

Comment: Just a side note: It is very unlikely that a society worshipping a semi-monotheistic female god is not matriarchal. You have to have a very good justification for this. Pantheon structures always reflect social structures and norms. Pantheons change and positions of gods change when societies change.

Comment: I think it's better as a comment than an answer: women have done pretty demanding jobs throughout history on a regular basis. Especially in times of need the gender roles fade and you do what you need to do. Often it isn't about what they can do, but culture. Culture is fluid, so fishing can be easily dominated by women if there's a cultural reason for it.

Comment: @AlexP Well, I don't think pearl diving is much less dangerous than hauling nets from a relatively safe boat. And we have examples of women doing physically more demanding jobs by custom. On the Solomon Islands, women used to craft canoes. Medieval Bulgaria conscripted women as soldiers in times of invasions. The latter might be exceptional but it confirms the idea that gender roles are flexible depending on the culture and the circumstances.

Comment: have you tried looking at the several traditional societies that live on boats on the ocean, I am willing to be everyone fishes.

Comment: @1995inHUN pearl fishng is on shore activity(shallow water),  fishing that deep water offshore activity, gone fishing and disappeared is clasical story. Men are expendable, women's are the only way to get next generation. Womens on fishing boats, modern ca 50 years ago, were a thing buuut u won't f them, they will f you, according to stories of those who whitnesed or had personal expirience. On rivers however, if it is dayly activiy everyone can fish, and some do, buuut there are fishing storis as well. Soo there is a difference which fishing we talk, sea or river.

Answer (score 5):

Women were involved in fishing in a few [Tasmanian Aboriginal communities](http://press-files.anu.edu.au/downloads/press/p74151/pdf/ch0154.pdf) and referenced [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/12/22/9724/pdf) as well, but I don't know if they where the main fisherpeople. But they where the predominant [divers for shellfish.](http://www.users.on.net/%7Eahvem/Fisheries/Abalone/abalone1.html)

hopefully that helps

Answer (score 3):

**Fish while Knitting.**

In many pre-industrial societies, one of the main activities done by women was making clothes for their family by hand. When you spend hours and hours every day knitting or weaving, it limits the other activities you can do. You can of course do other household chores during the day. But you cannot combine with something like Deer stalking or training horses, since the textile work requires one to stay in one place.

It *makes sense* for the women to do most of the fishing, if the particular style of fishing doesn't require much moving around. For example the fish are always in the same place, and the main job is to put out the lines and then wait (often for hours or days) for the fish to bite. In the meanwhile they carry on with the task of making clothes.

From a stereotypical point of view, if men are seen as hunters and women as gatherers, then this style of fishing is closer to gathering than hunting, since it involves only time and no special amount of talent. Not something young men will want to compete at to show they are better than all the other young men.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125033/discussion-on-answer-by-daron-is-there-a-culture-where-traditionally-women-fish).

Answer (score 0):

Warlike culture.
In society where men usually go to war for long periods of time you Would probably  see woman  Take over a lot of day to day  jobs that were normally done by fathers and husbands.  You could set up your  Society  To be Similar to the iron born from a song of ice and fire the men go out each season to raid and woman stay behind providing for the families usually by fishing.

If you don't want to make them warlike substitute war for trade have your men go on seasonal long business trips  To buy and sell goods leaving their fisherwives behind to provide for their family in their absence.